# Scheduled Reminders for membership not being sent

Tags: civimember, scheduled-reminders

We've looked on various threads on this topic without success. We have a contact who's membership schedule reminders are not being sent, and we can't see why.

- The membership is Active, auto-renewed monthly.
- no status override, (it did have an over-ridden end date, so we renewed the membership for several periods so it has an automatically generated end date well into the future)
- There are no records for this schedule reminder in civicrm_action_log

After checking the above we've also performed the Scheduled Job of Send Schedule Reminders and this didn't send the Schedule Reminder emails.

Particularly, we saw this: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/285. This suggests that the Membership Scheduled reminders won't go out if there is a status override or existing (annual) similar reminders. But we can't see that this is the case.

As far as we can see (from limited numbers of people on this membership), others are successfully receiving similar Schedule Reminder emails.

Any other ideas? Thanks for your help.

Civi 5.24.4, Drupal 7.69

Comment: What are the rules for the scheduled reminder you are sending out? Have you poked around in the membership tables to see if anything else looks different between this membership and ones getting it?

Comment: Hi @Zachary, thanks for the thoughts. The Schedule Reminder is for this particular membership, Auto renew = Reminder for both, 3 months after membership join date, limit /add recipients = neither. The membership was created in the admin end by our admin team, and has a clear membership join date more than 3 months ago. It is set to auto renew and all other details look ok. We can't find anything different about it... We've looked in the membership and action_log tables without seeing anything... to our somewhat untrained eyes...